# Pass dataset to SubReport

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I have a subreport and need to pass dataset from main report. How can I do this.

this is main report:

```
MainReport.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables[0]);
```

and I want to do this:

```
Subreport.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**I could solve with campagnolo_1's tip!**

My code:

```
Clases.ClsDb db = new Clases.ClsDb();
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from VREPORTE_PROVEEDORES", db.CadenaDeConexion);
SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ADM_EMPRESA", db.CadenaDeConexion);
da.Fill(ds, "VREPORTE_PROVEEDORES");
da2.Fill(ds, "ADM_EMPRESA");
rptDoc.Load("Reporte_Proveedores.rpt");
rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);

//Assign to first subreport(Cabecera) the second table (ADM_EMPRESA) in dataset
**rptDoc.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);**      //Campagnolo_1 Tip

this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
```

PERFECT !!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reference the main report in order to call the subreport. The code below uses the "Subreports" call and then the index of the subreport array.

```
MainReport.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(ds1.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: How about a little more explanation on why this works, possibly with related documentation quotes or links?

Comment: Thanx for helping me. I got an error on this line MainReport.Subreports[9].SetDataSource(ds1.Tables[0]);

Index was out of range....

Comment: You will need to know how many subreports are in your report and then choose the correct index. So if you only have one subreport, your index value would be [0] (index starts at 0, not 1). I'm sure it's just a typo on your part and you hit the 9 instead of the 0.